# forestplot: I want to modify the existing fpDrawNormalCI as suggested by the package

Tags: r, r-forestplot

Motivating example - I need to make a forestplot with filled and unfilled circles for the symbols.

```
forestplot(labeltext = labelstrings,
       fn.ci_norm = c(fpDrawCircleCI, fpDrawPointCI),
       mean=cbind(df.both$mauc, df.both$mcmax), 
       lower=cbind(df.both$lauc, df.both$lcmax),
       upper=cbind(df.both$uauc, df.both$ucmax),
       xlog=TRUE,
       boxsize=0.4,
       pch=1,
       xticks = c(0.33,0.5,0.8,1,1.25,2,3),
       col=fpColors(box=c("black","black"),line=c("black","black")),
       txt_gp = fpTxtGp(xlab=gpar(cex=1),ticks=gpar(cex=0.8)))`
```

but the symbols are slightly different in size (the fpDrawPointCI is smaller than the fpDrawCircleCI). If I try fpDrawPointCI, I can't get a vector of pch values to be accepted.

I tried

```
fn.ci_norm = c(fpDrawPointCI(pch=1), fpDrawPointCI(pch=19)
```

but that did not work.

So i tried creating this in my script, after loading the library(forestplot) but before my forestplot command.

```
fpDrawPointCIfilled <- function (lower_limit, estimate, upper_limit, size,
    y.offset = 0.5, clr.line, clr.marker, lwd, lty = 1, vertices, 
    vertices.height = 0.1, pch = 16, ...) 
{
    prFpDrawLine(lower_limit = lower_limit, upper_limit = upper_limit, 
        clr.line = clr.line, lwd = lwd, lty = lty, y.offset = y.offset, 
        vertices = vertices, vertices.height = vertices.height)
    box <- convertX(unit(estimate, "native"), "npc", valueOnly = TRUE)
    if (box >= 0 && box <= 1) {
        if (!is.unit(size)) {
        size <- unit(size, "snpc")
    }
    grid.points(x = unit(estimate, "native"), y = unit(y.offset, 
        "npc"), size = size, pch = pch, gp = gpar(fill = clr.marker, 
        col = clr.marker))
}}
```

It returns an error saying Error in fpDrawPointCIfilled() : could not find function prFpDrawLine. Could anyone post an example of how they have modified the fpDrawNormalCI functions in forestplot?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try using your initial clean code and adding this:

```
meta.ci.pch = 21
```

(or any other code) to set the size and shape for point styles. you can use `?points` to see all the styles of plotting characters. 
You can set a whole list of styles in a concatenated list that is as long as the number of plots. Just concatenate:

```
meta.ci.pch = c(19, 3, 9)
```

You will end up with distinct symbols for each.

And I think you can vary the size of the circles with:

```
circles.cex = 1.1   or   circles.cex = .8
```

or any other number indicating 110% of the default size or 80% of the default size. But the first should allow you to use hollow and filled shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting the specific issue you're having is that the prFpDrawLine function isn't exported from the forestplot library; it's an internal function.  A standard warning is that functions not exported may change without warning in future versions of the library.  That said...

If you replace `prFpDrawLine` with `forestplot:::prFpDrawLine`, the triple colon will look into the library for objects that may or may not be exported.  In this case, it will find the non-exported function `prFpDrawLine`, and your code should work.

Bill